# Error when attempting to Clean and Build Java project

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I recently upgraded a Java web application to use Java 11 and Tomcat 10. My IDE is Netbeans 16.

However when I attempt to Clean and Build the project within Netbeans, I get the following error:

`error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 11`

The solution at the following link kind of alludes to a similar problem however Im confused by the answer given. In fact, im not even sure if its related to my problem (Im not sure how to add sourcepath commands in Netbeans):

[Javadoc error: "option --boot-class-path not allowed with target 11"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106749/javadoc-error-option-boot-class-path-not-allowed-with-target-11)

Comment: Same thing. Your project is setting the `-Xbootclasspath` option somehow. It was removed in Java 10 and you use Java 11. You need to find how it is configured in your project or Netbeans options.

Comment: [This question comes up here regularly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22option+-Xbootclasspath%2Fp%3A+not+allowed+with+target%22+is%3AQuestion). Please review all of the existing answers, and update your question if none of them are applicable for you.

Comment: Thank you skomisa, I managed to find a solution in one of the answers you posted within the link above.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by putting:

`<property name="endorsed.classpath.cmd.line.arg" value="--patch-module  java.base='${toString:endorsed.classpath.path}'"/>`

in the projects 'build.xml' file just above the ending project tag.

This workaround was provided here at the following link:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2452